# Can I interrupt a method of a child in parent class?

Tags: objective-c

I declared `ParentClass`.

Then `ChildClass: ParentClass`

Is it possible to interrupt the overridden method in ChildClass after 'do something in ParentClass' so that 'do something in ChildClass' will not be executed?

//ParentClass.m

```
- (void)method
{
    /*do something in ParentClass*/
    /*try interrupting [child method]*/
}
```

//ChildClass.m

```
- (void)method
{
    [super method];
    /*do something in ChildClass*/
}
```

Comment: It'd be better if your question was in plain text outside the code rather than hidden as comments within the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't control a method up the call chain like this. Nor should a class have this sort of knowledge about its subclasses.

You'll have to find some way for `ClassB` to check the condition itself, whether via the return value from `-[ClassA method]`, or by calling another method first, or checking it directly.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You can not.  Parent classes know nothing about child classes.  You need to reconsider your structure if you're coming across this need...